# software for mapping links for site migration?

Tags: sitemap

I have a project where I am migrating a website from one platform to another, but the look and feel will still be the same (this is for standardization within an organization).

Through re-write rules, I have to maintain any of the links which someone could have bookmarked. The practical implication is that I have to inventory every link and make sure it goes to the right place on the new site.

Since there are often multiple paths to the same pages, I've found that site mapping software that do a hierarchical tree aren't giving me everything I need. The ones I've tried so far just show me the first, shortest path that landed them on that page. What I want to see is the inter-connectedness of the site -- if 5 pages all link to the sales page, I want to see that.

Is there a site-mapping software, preferably open source, what will show me the 'many-to-many' relationship of the site's pages, rather than the 'parent-child' hierarchy of navigation?

Answer (score 1):

the tools i use for site url mapping are: [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) and or [IISSEO](http://www.iis.net/download/SEOToolkit) the i export the data to Excel and work out the mapping from there. i work on the basis i am going to need a rewrite rule for each URL found on the existing site and therefore don't need to worry about how its linked.

After the site goes live i keep a close eye on web master tools as its never 100% accurate when doing this type of work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try A1 Website Analyzer. It will tell you of all URLs that use/link/redirect to an URL + at which lines the links are. Check this [analyze internal links](http://www.microsystools.com/products/website-analyzer/help/website-analyze-links-checks/) tutorial